# How can i combine multiple IF's on the same line

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

i have the following code that does not work:

```
If Range("I69") > 0 and If Range("I70") > 0 Then
DoSomeCalc's
end if
```

how can i make this function properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VBA, you don't have to repeat `If`, just use the connectors (`and`, `or`, etc):

```
If Range("I69") > 0 and Range("I70") > 0 Then
    DoSomeCalc's
End if
```